# Find the real values of k in a linear systen that does not have a unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

$$x+3y+kz=a$$
$$2x+(2k+2)y+(3k-2)z=b$$
$$kx+(k+4)y+4z=c$$

I have put them into a matrix and now am unsure where to go from here, do i make a RREF?
also how would i do it to make them consistent?

Comment: The second equation has $(3x-2)z$ which makes the system nonlinear. Did you mean $(3k-2)z$?

Comment: @Nitish yes sorry ill correct it now!

Answer (score 1):

So the matrix should just have the following form

$$Ax = b$$

where A is the matrix defining the system.  All of the x coefficients go in the first column y in the 2nd z in the third.

$$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1& 3 & k \\
2 & (2k+2) & (3k - 2) \\
k & (k+4) & 4 \end{array} \right) * \left( \begin{array}{c}
x \\
y  \\
z \end{array} \right) =  \left( \begin{array}{c}
a\\
b  \\
c \end{array} \right)$$

Take the [Determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) and set it to zero.  That will give you k values that make the matrix linearly dependent which are not unique.

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Det%5B%7B%7B1,%203,%20k%7D,%20%7B2,%202%20k%20%2b%201,%203%20k%20-%202%7D,%20%7Bk,%20k%20%2b%204,%204%7D%7D%5D)

$$Det[A] = -12 + 7 k^2 - 2 k^3 = 0$$

solving for the above equation gives the following values for k:

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B-12%2b7%20k%5E2-2%20k%5E3==0,k%5D)

$$k = 2$$
$${k }= {1\over4}(3 \pm   \sqrt{57})$$

Those are the values for k that define a system that has no unique solution.  All other k values do have a unique solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for $k\in \mathbb{R}$ such that the three given lines (interpreted as vectors) are linear dependent. If they are linear dependent for some value $k$, then the system has no unique solution.